# Running 2 projects using same domain using htaccess

Tags: laravel, .htaccess

I m not familiar with the rules of htaccess. I want to run two projects with the same domain or Root URL. Let's take an example I have the domain [www.example.com](http://www.example.com).
The first condition is that if users enter [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), the URL will direct users to demo/public folder, which is the Laravel project.
For the second condition, I have another small leaflet project outside laravel project i.e outside the demo folder. So, if users enter [www.example.com/map](http://www.example.com/map), the URL will direct users to map/index.html folder project.

Thank you so much.

My attempt:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/map
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /gis-app/$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /demo/public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Your forgot to ask a question ... But before you add that above: please understand that this is not how this site works. We are not here to do your work for you. We are here to help you fix your own solution. For that you need to have an own solution, you need to implement this yourself. Only then we can help. You need to add your current attempt along with an explanation what exactly is wrong with your solution, where exactly you need help. You will find literally _thousands_ of existing examples here on SO. That should give you a good starting point.

Comment: Ok, I have put my attempt, but I m really a noob on this, I m doing this the first time and I really don't know what I have done. Thanks, @arkascha

Comment: What site/pages are available under `www.example.com` itself? Why not make the Laravel project your "main" project available at `www.example.com` and put the `map` folder inside Laravel's `public` folder and make it work?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that way too. But inside the map folder, there is an old map application, many scripts ajax functions running, I need to make lots of changes in the route for that ajax call. My last option is that, but without keeping the map folder inside laravel project it's running well right now, so if there is a trick with htaccess it will be easy. Thanks @brombeer